# Spring Boot Thymeleaf Dropdown List

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to persist values in database from a dropdown list in ***Spring Boot***, ***thymeleaf*** but the database is populated with empty values.

Apparently the controller doesn't pass the value.

While I can fetch and display the values in ***GET*** but I cannot persist them in ***POST***.

I'm not able to get a clear example from anywhere and even the examples on ***Thymeleaf*** are not clear.

Please help with some good example or a solution.

The code is as below.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signupPost(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,
        Model model, BindingResult result) {

        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            userService.saveUser(user);
        }
        return "redirect:/";

    }

}
```

The `User` class is as below

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "award_partner_id")
    private AwardPartner awardPartner;

    getters and setters....
}
```

The HTML snippet is here:

```
<!--Award Partner-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Award Partner</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 selectContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span> 
                <select name="awardPartner" roleId="awardPartner" id="awardPartner"
                th:field="*{awardPartner}" class="form-control selectpicker">
                <option value="">Select Award Partner</option>
                <option th:each="awardPartner : ${awardPartners}"
                    th:value="${awardPartner.id}"
                    th:text="${awardPartner.title}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: In your HTML, there is nothing about an user.

Comment: @SébastienTemprado apologies but I didn't get you. I've not posted the user part as it is persisting fine. Only the County and AwardPartner snippet are facing an issue.

Comment: What do you get in the user object under `awardPartner` in the post request?

Comment: I get null under AwardPartner in post request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form tag, I think there is `th:object="user"`.

In your select tag, there is `th:field="*{awardPartner}"`. It means that you will put the selected value (the value of the selected option tag) in the field awardPartner of the object user. This field `awardPartner` is of type `AwardPartner`

In the option values, you have got an id (int or string?) as value but not an object of type `AwardPartner`